# Growth Rate of Supremum of Random Walk (with negative drift)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, random-walk

Let $(X_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, with $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ finite and negative. Define $S_n := X_1 + ... + X_n$, and $M_n := \max(S_1,S_2,...,S_n)$.

It follows from the final bullet point of Sangchul Lee's answer to this question [Is the expectation of the supremum of a random walk with negative drift finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336488/is-the-expectation-of-the-supremum-of-a-random-walk-with-negative-drift-finite) that if $X_i$ have infinite variance, then $\mathbb{E}(M_n) \rightarrow +\infty$ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$. However I am curious how quickly this growth to infinity occurs?

---

I am not sure if there is a general answer in terms of the distribution of $X_i$, so I started by trying to use a simple test example. I defined the $X_i$ variables to be absolutely continuous with density function $f(x) := \frac{2}{(x+3)^3}$ for $x \in [-2,\infty)$.

This is the simpliest example I could think of which would have a finite negative mean (in this case the mean is $-1$), yet infinite variance. However, with this example, I am struggling to work out how quickly $\mathbb{E}(M_n)$ diverges.

By a **very** rough numerical calculation, it seems as though the density function of $M_2$ decays like $O(\frac{1}{x^{2.8}})$ (maybe the true exponent is $e$?). I'm guessing that as $n \rightarrow +\infty$ the density of $M_n$ tends to a decay rate of $O(\frac{1}{x^2})$, but again I have no idea how to attack this.

---

Does anyone know what kind of analytic tools I can use to tackle this problem? Cheers.

Comment: This is a delicate example to analyze, because it is right at the borderline of having infinite variance. A density  of the form $a/(x+b)^{2.5}$ would be easier.

Comment: @YuvalPeres I’m happy to be shown the analysis of a simpler example. I only choose my denominator exponent to be 3 because I don’t feel I know enough to know which examples are “simpler”.